# Transfer file from SFTP to ADLS

Tags: java, sftp, databricks, azure-data-lake, sshj

We are currently in the process of exploring the [sshj](https://github.com/hierynomus/sshj) library to download a file from SFTP path into ADLS. We are using the [example](https://github.com/hierynomus/sshj/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/net/schmizz/sshj/examples/SFTPDownload.java) as reference.

- We have already configured the ADLS Gen2 storage in Databricks to be accessed as an `abfss` URL.
- We are using scala within Databricks.

1. How should we pass the `abfss` path as `FileSystemFile` object in the get step ?

   ```
   sftp.get("test_file", new FileSystemFile("abfss://<container_name>@a<storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net/<path>"));
   ```
2. Is the destination supposed to be a file path only or file path with file name?

Answer (score 0):

Use streams. First obtain `InputStream` of the source SFTP file:

```
RemoteFile f = sftp.open(sftpPath);
InputStream is = f.new RemoteFileInputStream(0);
```

*([How to read from the remote file into a Stream?](https://github.com/hierynomus/sshj/issues/533))*

---

Then obtain `OutputStream` of the destination file on ADLS:

```
OutputStream os = adlsStoreClient.createFile(adlsPath, IfExists.OVERWRITE);
```

*([How to upload and download a file from my locale to azure adls using java sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60660674/850848))*

---

And copy from the first to the other:

```
is.transferTo(os);
```

*([Easy way to write contents of a Java InputStream to an OutputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43157/850848))*